# Vaadin image in gridlayout (resizing)

Tags: java, eclipse, vaadin7

I made a Vaadin program with a gridlayout in eclipse (a server - minesweeper program).  When I preview in eclipse I see the following.

[image]

When I call the same in for example firefox I get

[image]

I believe it's a problem with resizing or something similar.

```
 public void drawBoard() {
    this.removeAllComponents();
    boardDTO = gameManager.getCurrentGame().getBoardDTO();
    Integer w = 30 * boardDTO.getNumOfRow() + 80;
    Integer h = boardDTO.getNumOfCol() * 30 + 150;
    String wPx = w.toString() + "px";
    String hPx = h.toString() + "px";
    this.setWidth(wPx);
    this.setHeight(hPx);
    gridLayout = new GridLayout(boardDTO.getNumOfRow(), boardDTO.getNumOfCol());
    gridLayout.setSpacing(true);
    gridLayout.setMargin(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < boardDTO.getNumOfRow(); i++) {
        ArrayList<Cell> row = new ArrayList<Cell>();
        for (int j = 0; j < boardDTO.getNumOfCol(); j++) {
            Cell cell = new Cell(boardController, boardDTO.getCellDTO(i, j));
            cell.setVisible(true);
            row.add(cell);
            gridLayout.addComponent(cell);
            cell.addClickListener(cell);
            boardDTO.getCellDTO(i, j).addObserver(cell);
        }
        grid.add(row);
    }
    this.addComponent(gridLayout);
}

public Cell(BoardController controller, CellDTO cellDTO) {

    posX = cellDTO.getPosX();
    posY = cellDTO.getPosY();
    boardController = controller;
    setSizeUndefined();
    currentImg = BoardView.getCurrentImage(cellDTO);       


    //setStyleName();
    loadImage();
    setContent(layout);

}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void loadImage() {
    layout.removeAllComponents();

    image = new Image("", new ThemeResource(currentImg));
    image.setSizeUndefined();

    Integer w=(int)getWidth();
    Integer h=(int)getHeight();
   //layout.setWidth(w+"px");
    //layout.setHeight(h+"px");

  //  image.setWidth(w.toString()+"px");
   // image.setHeight(h.toString()+"px");

    layout.addComponent(image);
    layout.setExpandRatio(image, 1.0f);
    layout.setComponentAlignment(image, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
}
```

Any suggestions how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Use a real browser for preview. The firefox look should be considered the good one. You can change the default browser to external web browser in eclipse under the General->Web Browser settings.